# Wordplay Puzzle

Tags: word, cipher

So, as I was flipping through my papers from school, I realized I made an unscramble puzzle for my friends. I was interested if anyone could solve these words with a hard twist. Every scrambled word has one extra letter in it's code. If you remove all the correct extra letters in order, you should get the name of an insanely popular video game. Each scrambled word is in all caps, so gessing which one is scrambled shouldn't be too hard. So, here's the puzzle.

1. The wind blew out the torch in the YBRPCT.
2. The SEERUTHAEO scales around 200 feet high.
3. My technology cave is not LINCBRDEYLI cozy.
4. Dr. N. Sane's lab is made entirely with RETINADG.
5. Nick's office is DREEPTCII and depressing.
6. Reed's library is filled to the BSMRI with books.
7. Liam's nephew INIREBDHTE a playhouse (which is a house where plays are performed).
8. Esther's EATTSAE is rather impressive.
9. Every Halloween, Doug has a haunted house party near his VYEGDARARS.
10. Dreamer's U.F.O LOOBRARYATI is near a crashed plane.
11. Captain A. Hab's ship is somewhere off the OSACCT of Sri Lanka.
12. Lucas's Music Hall has AEIDCNSRES in value since 1850.

Note that, if needed, I will provide definitions of the scrambled words.
Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. CRYPT + B
>  2. TREEHOUSE + A
>  3. INCREDIBLY + L
>  4. GRANITE + D
>  5. DECREPIT + I
>  6. BRIM + S
>  7. INHERITED + B
>  8. ESTATE + A
>  9. GRAVEYARD + S
>  10. LABORATORY + I
>  11. COAST + C
>  12. INCREASED + S
>  The added letters give **BALDI'S BASICS** (in Education and Learning) which is apparently a new indie video game that I've now just heard of.

Comment: I was expecting the puzzle to take just a bit longer than that, like one day, not really 10 minutes. Great job!

Comment: @KingDedede'sSecretAssistant Great puzzle, nonetheless! $(+1)$ :D